# Point example.com to webserver in DNS record

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, mac-osx-server

I have a Mac Mini Server (named Server) with the following DNS setup

```
Primary Zone: example.com
   mysql-host.example.com machine (10.0.0.101)
   server.example.com machine (10.0.0.100)
   server.example.com nameserver (10.0.0.100)
   www.example.com machine (10.0.0.102)
```

www.example.com is a linux box with Apache. How do I get both example.com and www.example.com to work. Right now, I can view my website with www.example.com only. I know there's nothing that points example.com to the IP, but when I create a machine record without a hostname I get an error (This machine record cannot be created without a host name.).

Comment: An `A` record for domain.com would suffice. Have you tried a "." for the hostname?

Comment: Um, did you try entering `domain.com`?

Comment: I can't enter domain.com, I get that error: This machine record cannot be created without a host name @MichaelHampton

Comment: @NathanC I can't enter a "." either.

Comment: Try a `@`, maybe.

Comment: I was able to use example.com by editing the config file manually instead of using the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this in the regular Server application interface, simply by entering the full domain name (e.g. "example.com") in the Host Name field. There are a few notes, though:

- Make sure the interface is in "Show All Records" mode (selectable from the "action" (gear icon) pop-up menu under the DNS Record list. Without this, it hides (and doesn't let you control) critical details, like the zones themselves.
- When creating the Machine Record, it normally suffixes the "Host Name" field with the zone name (e.g. Host Name="www" in zone "example.com" will create a record for "www.example.com"). But this is not done if the Host Name *is* the zone name (and you can see this at the top of the window). For example, if the zone is "example.com", and you type "example.co" in the field, it'll show "example.co.example.com" at the top of the window -- but as soon as you add the last "m", it changes to just "example.com".
- Do not try to use a "." to terminate the Host Name (as the standard FQDN syntax requires), leave the field blank, or use "@" (bind zone file shorthand) -- the server interface will reject all of these. Note that it will be converted to standard FQDN format when it's written into the zone file.

As you apparently discovered, you can also do it by editing the zone file directly. But of course I have some notes about that as well:

- The zone files are in a nonstandard location: /Library/Server/named/ (with named.conf right alongside them).
- Be sure to copy the format of the entries Server.app creates *exactly*. I haven't experimented much with Server v3.x, but with an earlier versions I once had the admin interface get confused because I didn't use the expected number of spaces between fields.

Answer (score 0):

what are you using for your DNS? Bind does weird things with apex domains.. but like the other comments say, you could probably just specifiy

```
example.com. A 10.0.0.102
```

i assume if you then did a

```
dig axfr example.com
```

you would no longer see an SOA returned.. i dont know what implications this would have for your other records.

I believe this will also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022324/how-to-setup-dns-for-an-apex-domain-no-www-pointing-to-a-heroku-app

Comment: I'm using Apple OS X Server 3.1.1 (Mavericks).